# SVN Checkout failed because of logon failure

Tags: authentication, svn, tortoisesvn, credentials, svn-checkout

I am trying to do a SVN checkout using tortoise SVN on a folder that is on a different server using the file:// method. Instead of doing it, it only gives me the error:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>
> file://xxxxxxxxxxx/svnrep/xxx/trunk
>
> Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>
> Can't open file '\xxxxxx\svnrep\xxx\trunk\format': Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

What could be wrong?

Comment: 1. Don't use `file://` protocol for SVN, 2. Did you try command line with specifying user name and password?

Comment: What would you suggest me to use instead of file://?

Comment: `svn`, or `http(s)`? `svn` protocol is the easiest to set up. See [Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) from the SVN Book (bottom of the page tells why `file://` is bad).

Comment: First of all, local protocol is `file:///`. Second - user, under which you mounted remote drive (user in "a different server") doesn't have all needed permissions at FS-level to read directory-tree with repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a problem connecting to your host server, try this:

1. Do a TortoiseSvn-checkout in the folder of your choice.
2. Press the "..." button next to the repository url input field.
3. In the file selection window, enter \\*SERVER_NAME* and press *ENTER*.
4. When prompted, enter your network credentials and check "remember my credentials".
5. Browse to your repository and select it.
6. Back in the SVN checkout window press the same "..." again.
7. You are now browsing into your SVN repository.
8. Do your checkout as usual.

**Note:**
Using SVN over file:/// is not the most optimal way but it's not going to break your SVN repository even if the network fails. SVN creates a transaction then promote it to a revision once completed. Worst case you'll end up with an uncommitted transaction in the SVN database but your repository will still be fully functional. To clean up these failed transactions, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deadtxns